# Splitting an array with multiple seperators (Special chars, and string)

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, string, split

I have this string here

```
"\n\nFlour (Contains: Wheat Flour,\n\nMalted Barley Flour, Niacin,\n\nReduced Iron, Thiamine Mononi-\n\ntrate, Riboflavin, Folic Acid), Water,\n\nSourdough (6.4%) (Contains: Water,\n\nFlour [Wheat Flour, Malted Barley\nFlout, Niacin, Reduced Iron,\nThiamine Mononitrate, Riboflavin,\nFolic Acid], Yeast), Salt, Wheat\nGerm Semolina (Contains: Durum\nWheat Semolina, Niacin, Ferrous\nSulphate, Thiamine Mononitrate,\nRiboflavin, Folic Acid).\n"
```

Running a simple `data.split(',')` and `this.ingredients[i] = this.ingredients[i].replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm,"").trim()`

Gives me the following

```
"Flour (Contains: Wheat Flour",
"Malted Barley Flour",
"Niacin",
"Reduced Iron",
"Thiamine Mononi-trate",
"Riboflavin",
"Folic Acid)",
"Water",
"Sourdough (6.4%) (Contains: Water",
...
```

But I'd like to make an additional split at `(Contains:` so that this string

`"Flour (Contains: Wheat Flour",` will become `"Flour", "Wheat Flour",`

I was wondering how I can use two different sort of separators to achieve what I'd like to have done. Should I use a different approach instead of split?

Comment: hi. i'm not quite sure what you want to do. but is this what you want ?
https://jsfiddle.net/43sxh2t7/

you can add string as parameter of split()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a regular expression as the delimiter in `split`. Then use `|` to specify multiple delimiters.

```
data.split(/\(Contains: |,/)
```